# cannot submit a form in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-forms

This is my login.component.html

```
    <form #user class="form-horizontal" method="post" (ngSubmit)="login($event)">
    <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Email</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email"  placeholder="Enter your Email"/>
    </div>
    <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"  [(ngModel)]="user.password" placeholder="Enter your Password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my login.component.ts
    export class LoginComponent{

```
user = {email:'', password:''};
constructor (private dataservice: DataService){

}//End of constructor

//Login Function
login(){
    console.log(this.user);
    this.dataservice.loginValidate(this.user).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    },error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
}//end of function
```

}

This is my data.service.ts

```
    @Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    //Method to login validate
    loginValidate(user) {
            const post_data =  this.http.post('http://localhost/charan/postdata.php',{
            username: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }).subscribe(
            res => {
            console.log(res);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

When I am trying to post the form data, it is showing below error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at LoginComponent.push../src/app/login/login.component.ts.LoginComponent.login (login.component.ts:35)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginComponent.html:9)
    at handleEvent (core.js:9953)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11046)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:10749)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7415)
    at core.js:8892
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:3415)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:133)

This is my package.json

```
{
```

"name": "exproj1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add the 'user' object which used to bind the form values?

Comment: Even I am getting the same error

Comment: @RaedKhalaf I didn't understand

Comment: you used this in the form[(ngModel)]="user.email", this means that there is a 'user' object in the login.component.ts, can you add its implementation to the question body?

Comment: @RaedKhalaf, Thank you for your reply. I just defined user as "user;" above the constructor method in login.component.ts.

Comment: did it worked ?

Comment: @RaedKhalaf No..

Comment: The problem is at subscribe keyword,you might be doing something wrong in either in your service or comp.ts class,that's the reason you're getting this error.Did you install observable or rxjs?If not import those packages install and use them.

Comment: The error is here ''this.dataservice.loginValidate(this.user).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    },error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);'' because there is void in service class.Try to change method parameter having some value,then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. the value of **name** and **[(ngModel)]** should be same.
2. you have to create an user object in the  login.component.ts file.

I can show a code example.

**login.component.html**

```
<form class="pt-3" (submit)="onLogin()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="should have min. 6 character with a number">
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Keep Me logged in for 7 days</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Login</button>
        </form>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   email: String;
   password : String;
    onLogin(){
        const user = {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        }

        this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
          if(data.success){
            this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
            this.flashMessage.show('succefully loggedin !', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 5000});
            this.router.navigate(['/user/dashboard']);
          } else {
            this.flashMessage.show(data.msg, {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout:2000});
            this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
          }
        });
      }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(this.url + `/users/authenticate`, user, {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
  }
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: it is showing error this.http.post(...) map is not a function

Comment: add import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; in your auth.service.ts file.

Comment: I did that, it is showing the error - error TS2339 property subscribe does not exist on type void

Comment: I think you are using angular 6. I have faced such kind of problem while using angular 6. can you show me package.json file.

Comment: I have added package.json above.

Answer (score -1):

Remove #user ref from form or change it's name. If you are using this instance into ts then it will be problematic.

Comment: you have defined user; you should define user object like user = { email : "", password : ""}

Comment: I have defined as you said, now i am getting the error as response is not defined

Comment: this is commented line in your service code `//let user = Response.json();` then where you are getting this error please tell me. if you un-commented this line then this is wrong it should be `let user  = response.json()`

Comment: it is showing the error at this line "}).map(response: Response) => {"